# Are reference variables allowed to destruct their objects in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have the following (bizarre) code:

```
int* getPointer(int* p) {
    int* x_p = nullptr;
    int& x = *p;
    if(x==7) {
        x_p = &x;
    }
    return x_p;
}
```

Since `x` is assigned the value of `p`, I feel like this code is unsafe: When `x` goes out of scope, it's associated object can be destructed, leaving `x_p` in an invalid state.

However, I tested this code, and it worked fine. Was I just lucky or does the fact that `x` is a reference variable change the destruction sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `*p` is obviously not destroyed simply by `x` going out of scope, otherwise references would inherently cause double-"frees" almost every single time you used them.

Answer (score 3):

Creating or assigning a reference does not create a new object, so there is nothing to destroy. Therefore, when a reference goes out of scope, a destructor is not called. To state that even more clearly: a destructor is not called when a reference goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

References aren't destructed, objects are.  The lifetime of the *object*, i.e. `*p`, is unrelated to the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Destroying a raw pointer or reference won't destroy the object that it's pointing to.

The situation is actually the *opposite* — when, in your example, you manually allocate some memory, save its address in a raw pointer, and allow the pointer to be destroyed, unless you have a copy of the address it was pointing to you're unable to free the memory and you have a memory leak.

If you want to have a pointer that destroys the object to which it's pointing, when it's destroyed, use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/).

Comment: Learn "a" and "the" please! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for drawing my attention to it. If you have a moment, please correct my answer to let me see where I made mistakes.